# Questions about Fitness Equipment

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

Is it acceptable to ask **fitness equipment** related questions on Fitness.SE?  I'm specifically referring to my treadmill and my question would be along the lines of *why does my treadmill do X at certain speeds*?

Looking at the [FAQ](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/faq), I see that **gear and gadgets used during exercise** is fair game but I suspect this question may be off topic.

Obviously I haven't asked it yet on the chance it will be closed as off-topic, hence why I don't have anything to link to.

Comment: I'd have to see your final questions to really give you a good answer. We've left it somewhat ambiguous, because it hasn't been a problem so far.

Comment: @IvoFlipse I suppose I'll have to risk it then.. okay will get back after I write it up.

Comment: Presumably anyone who is asking a question (barring product recommendations) about fitness equipment will use it for or during exercise.

Comment: @Marvin Do you have a lot of knowledge about treadmills? Or do you use other gadgets? If so, that could be a good subject for the [Fitness blog](http://fitness.blogoverflow.com/).

Comment: @MattChan Unfortunately I don't know a lot about treadmills and admittedly I'm an amateur in the whole F&N area. I'm trying to soak up all the info I can and F&N has been a great resource so far!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Our [faq](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/faq) states "gear and gadgets used during exercise" is on-topic. Presumably, as I said in [my comment](https://fitness.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239/questions-about-fitness-equipment#comment459_239) on your question, a question about fitness equipment should be on-topic. Recommendations are debatable and might be closed as "Not Constructive" but are not entirely off-topic.

Your question of, "Why does my treadmill do X at certain speeds?" sounds like it is fair game for the site. Without knowing what your question exactly is, as Ivo [pointed out](https://fitness.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239/questions-about-fitness-equipment#comment457_239), (and since you made your meta post, you don't appear to have posted it), it's not as clear as to whether it is on-topic or not.

Comment: Thanks Matt, I'll update this question if I get around to posting it. For now I'll leave it as resolved :)

Comment: Has the answer to this changed? http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/22196/will-any-lubricant-work-on-any-treadmill got flagged for being off-topic for asking about treadmill lubricants.

Comment: Same issue with [Does the Bluetooth have to be activated on the phone for Fitbit Surge to track the sleep time?](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/q/25340/3806) : got downvoted + close votes.

Answer (score 2):

This question is similar to asking questions on SO related to specific IDEs, rather than the code generated by them. It seems that on SO these questions are acceptable [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eclipse)[[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xcode)[[3]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio), so I suggest that it would be appropriate here as well. Simply tag them "fitness-equipment" or the like.

Answer (score 1):

Shopping recommendations have typically been off topic. The [stackexchange blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) defines how they should be rephrased:

> Here’s one way to ask:
>
> Q: What’s the best low light point-and-shoot camera?
>
> A: Canon S90 and Lumix LX3.
>
> Here’s another way to ask:
>
> Q: How do I tell which point-and-shoot cameras take good low light
>   photos?
>
> A: I strongly recommend looking for something with
>
> a fast lens (2.0 at least) reasonable ISO handling (at least 400, but
>   preferably 800) the biggest sensor available The sum of these factors
>   are really critical for low light situations.

From: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/