# Are questions about FitBit etc. considered off-topic?

Tags: discussion

I'm a frequent user of fitness.se for ~3 months now and in that time I've come across many questions about specific fitness gadgets, that I feel just don't belong. I'm not even talking about 'do you think FitBit will help me stick to my diet?'-kinda questions, but more in the direction of 'why doesn't it count my steps?'

I'm pretty sure, those are technical questions and are therefore off-topic. Most manufacturers provide a board of their own, where such difficulties can be solved, so I just don't see this site as the place to ask that question.

It is a bit of a grey are though, that's why I ask. How technical does a question concerning gadgets have to be to be off topic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those types of questions are on-topic for this site. This is something we didn't want to push out of our [faq section](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) when we came up with what the site was about:

> - gear and gadgets used during exercise

However, recommendations about products are not though. Aspects of gadgets outside of the use for fitness, such as the [economics of fitness](https://fitness.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/411/is-it-ok-to-ask-questions-about-the-economics-of-gym-equipment-if-not-where) are not on topic.